# Lcurd class not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have controller name as 'CashFlowdata'. In controller I am having code that is :

```
namespace App\Modules\CashFlowdata\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use App\Modules\CashFlowdata\Models\CashModel; 
use App\Modules\CashFlowdata\Lcurd\CashFlowdataLcurd;

use Auth, Womp, Graphs, Projects, Input , Permissions, LcrudForm, LcrudTable, Redirect, Session, Meta;

class CashFlowdataController extends Controller
{
    private $lcrud;
    
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth'); 
          $this->lcrud = new CashFlowdataLcurd();
    }
}
```

But in that I am getting error for

```
Class 'App\Modules\CashFlowdata\Lcurd\CashFlowdataLcurd' not found
```

But the file is there and that is with  the same name.

Answer (score 1):

If class and file have the same name (case sensitive), maybe you need a

`composer dump-autoload`

PS: Check 'lcurd' vs 'lcrud'

Comment: Yes it is case sensitive. Error was because of that. Thank you..!!